# Create a new resouce and its relations in one go in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an object and its to-many relations in one POST, but I keep getting 400 `'attribute': 'This field is required`, How do I create both sides of this relationship in one POST?

What I have right now is:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Value(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attribute = models.ForiegnKey(Attribute, related_name="allowed_values")
```

Pretty standard one-to-many relationship with a related name.  My serializers look like

```
class ValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Value


class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Attribute

    allowed_values = ValueSerializer(many=True)
```

my data is:

```
{'name': 'new attribute',
 'allowed_values': [{'name': 'value1'}, {'name':'value2'}, {'name':'value3'}]}
```

While reading the source code, i see something that looks like it should pop off the related value fields until after the attributes object has been saved, but I cannot seem to get the serializer to invoke like this.

Answer (score 0):

DRF expected `attribute` field by default, because you didn't define field names explicitly.

Define all you fields, like this:

```
class ValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Value
        fields = ('name',)

class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    allowed_values = ValueSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('name', 'allowed_values',)
```

Defining field names explicitly is a good practice. It prevents any potential problems in case any other model fields are added afterwards.